# How to use Polymer JS without polymer-cli?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Polymer working well with polymer-cli but is any way to run polymer application without polymer-cli and how we integrate it with struts, grails frameworks?

Comment: It is but it can give you headache - polymer is designed in a way to be used with all the crap, philosophy and build system.